# Angular directive to find word. Can't find words with diacritics

Tags: angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive, coffeescript

with $filter I get translation, and with scope.keywords I get words I want to find. It works pretty good except it can't find words with diacritic characters like: "cześć". Can anyone help me?

```
.directive 'highlight', ($filter) ->
    component = (scope, element, attrs) ->

        scope.highlightedText = $filter('translate')(scope.highlight)
        if !attrs.highlightClass
            attrs.highlightClass = 'angular-highlight'

        replacer = (match, item) ->
            console.log match
            '<span class="' + attrs.highlightClass + '">' + match + '</span>'

        tokenize = (keywords) ->
            keywords = keywords.replace(new RegExp(',$', 'g'), '').split(',')
            i = undefined
            l = keywords.length
            i = 0
            while i < l
                keywords[i] = '\\b' + keywords[i].replace(new RegExp('^ | $', 'g'), '') + '\\b'
                i++
            console.log keywords
            keywords

        scope.$watch 'keywords', ->
            if !scope.keywords or scope.keywords == ''
                element.html scope.highlightedText
                return false
            tokenized = tokenize(scope.keywords)
            regex = new RegExp(tokenized.join('|'), 'gmi')
            console.log tokenized
            console.log regex
            # Find the words
            html = scope.highlightedText.replace(regex, replacer)
            console.log html
            element.html html
            return
        return

    {
        link: component
        replace: false
        scope:
            highlight: '@'
            keywords: '@'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from

```
keywords[i] = '\\b' + keywords[i].replace(new RegExp('^ | $', 'g'), '') + '\\b'
```

change to 
`keywords[i] = '\\b' + keywords[i].replace(new RegExp('^ | $', 'g'), '')`